# How to use YouTube Player Fragment in kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, null, android-youtube-api

I'm trying to show some Youtube videos in my Android app. After reading some tutorials, I decided to use YoutubePlayerFragment. However, when I run my code below, I just got some error.

```
package com.example.signlanguage

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment
import com.example.signlanguage.databinding.FragmentYoutubeBinding


class youtubeFragment : Fragment(), YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
    private var _binding: FragmentYoutubeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentYoutubeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val youTubePlayerFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment) as YouTubePlayerFragment
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(getString(R.string.api), this)
    }

    override fun onInitializationSuccess(
        provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider?,
        player: YouTubePlayer?,
        wasRestored: Boolean
    ) {
        if(player == null) return
        if(wasRestored) {
            player.play()
        } else {
            player.cueVideo(getString(R.string.video_id))
            player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
        }
    }

    override fun onInitializationFailure(
        p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?,
        p1: YouTubeInitializationResult?
    ) {
        Log.d("Youtube Player", "Failed to initialize");
    }


}
```

And this is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".youtubeFragment">
    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
        android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="Instantiatable" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the error message I got from the Logcat:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.signlanguage/com.example.signlanguage.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment`

I've try to change
`val youTubePlayerFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment) as YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(getString(R.string.api), this)` into `val youTubePlayerFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment) as YouTubePlayerFragment? youTubePlayerFragment?.initialize(getString(R.string.api), this)`, and ended up getting a black video view in my screen. I guess this is because the player is null, but I don't know why this could happen.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `findViewById` call is returning null, which means it can't find a fragment with that ID.

Your code looks fine, but apparently [you can't inflate a fragment layout that contains another fragment](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments):

> Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a `<fragment>`. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically

That's old documentation, but I can't find anything that says it's changed. I'd try swapping it for a container instead, and create and add the `YouTubePlayerFragment` in code with a transaction instead (you'll probably want to give it a tag, so you can check it's not already added)

Comment: I tried this:         `childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            add(R.id.youtube_fragment,youTubePlayerFragment as Fragment)
            commit()
        } `  and removed the inflation part (also the view bindings).But I just got a blank view... Do I need to add anything to have my fragment show on the screen? There is nothing reference to the xml file in the code now.

Comment: You need to make sure you have a container layout for the fragment to go into (a ``FrameLayout`` is fine) with the ID you're using in the ``add`` command - ``youtube_fragment". You can use the Layout Inspector in Android Studio while your app is running to look at what's on the screen - that way you can see if that blank space is your youtube fragment (in which case it's there, it's just not displaying anything) or if it's just the empty container (in which case your fragment isn't getting added). You can also check if stuff is in the hierarchy but has 0 height, that kind of thing